# Android - Removing the title bar itself in AppCompatActivity

Tags: android

I made a fresh activity using the Tabbed Fragment Viewer layout example as readily available using Android Studio. However, I want to maximize the space of my screen and I decided to remove the title and the menu buttons. I was able to achieve this by doing this in my onCreate function:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    //more lines here      
}
```

and I commented out the Overrides for creating and handling the menu selection.

This did clear out the title and removed the options menu button (3 square buttons). However, it did not remove the title bar itself. The bar is still there but it does not have contents. It is an eyesore if anything, since I have this blue bar right on top of the tabs that manage the fragments.

I want to remove the bar altogether and not just remove the contents.

Comment: `getSupportActionBar().hide()`

Comment: change theme 
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

Comment: @Blackbelt it is beyond me on how tf I managed to miss that. It works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try with this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {          
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide(); //<< this
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

or add in manifest

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: the `getSupportActionBar().hide();` worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the activities where you want to have no action bar use a theme derived from

```
Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar
```

or

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

This activity will never be able to show the action bar unless you supply your own via setSupportActionBar(Toolbar).

Answer (score 0):

use this under the `<activity` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`  :
`android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"`

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Manifest (@android:style didn't work for me):

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```